# Java 8 - Map an Array/Collection in place

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way in Java 8 to transform an Array/Collection using `map()` without having to reassign the created copy, e.g.

```
Arrays.stream(array).mapInPlace(x -> x / 100);
list.stream().mapInPlace(e -> e.replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

instead of

```
array = Arrays.stream(array).map(x -> x / 100).toArray();
list = list.stream().map(e -> e.replaceAll(" ", "")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

?

If not, what's the reason for this design decision?

Comment: And you also have [Map.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe using [`List::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) in your case can help you :

```
Arrays.asList(array).replaceAll(x -> x / 100);
```

and

```
list.replaceAll(e -> e.replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

---

[Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/oGZWKz)

---

Good point from [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182690/java-8-map-an-array-collection-in-place/52182762?noredirect=1#comment91316074_52182762), in case you need the index you can use [`Arrays::setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-int:A-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) :

```
Arrays.setAll(array, x -> array[x] / 100);
```

Or more better if you want your job to be in parallel you can use [`Arrays::parallelSetAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSetAll-int:A-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) :

```
Arrays.parallelSetAll(array, x -> array[x] / 100);
```

Comment: …and in case you need the index, `Arrays.setAll​(array, index -> expression);`

Comment: Thank you @Holger this is nice trick even we can use `parallelSetAll`